# VertexAI serving_container_predict_route for custom container returns 404

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have built a mar file and a container to launch it with this command
`CMD ["torchserve", "--start", "--ncs", "--ts-config", "/home/config.properties", "--model-store", "/home/model-store/", "--models", "mymodel=my_model.mar"]`. And I expose the port `8081` as specified in my `config.properties`.
Now if run the container locally, I'm able to communicate with it using this `url="http://localhost:8081/v1/models/my_model:predict"`.
and I upload my model using this predict route:

```
model = aiplatform.Model.upload(
    display_name=model_display_name,
    description=model_description,
    serving_container_image_uri=CUSTOM_PREDICTOR_IMAGE_URI,
    serving_container_predict_route="/v1/models/my_model:predict",
    serving_container_health_route=health_route,
    serving_container_ports=serving_container_ports,
)
```

However, the problem comes when i deploy the endpoint, the model is loaded and ready, i see the health ping with a `200` but when i try to send a prediction request I get this response:

```
{
  "code": 404,
  "type": "ModelNotFoundException",
  "message": "Model not found: my_model"
}
```

But I can see that there is a log:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.aiplatform.logging.OnlinePredictionLogEntry", "deployedModelId":"***", "endpoint":"projects/***/locations/***/endpoints/***", "error":{…}, "instanceCount":"1"}
```

If i try from the sample request I get 404`

```
The operation failed due to the following error(s):

Invalid HTTP message.
```

What should I put as predict route?